# Google Compute Engine with Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, google-cloud-platform, gpu, google-compute-engine

How can I run a GPU consumed Java application on IntelliJ if the machine doesn't have GPU in it? 
How can I connect to Google compute instance in the cloud through IntelliJ?
I Would like to run the application remotely by making use of compute engine GPU power

I tried to use Google stack driver debug plugin, but no luck with that. Remember, I'm not talking about just the deployment.

Comment: Do you have a [GCE VM instance running with an attached GPU](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gpus/)?

Comment: Yes, I do have.

Comment: @PatrickW 
And that's where I'm seeking answers. I wanted to make use of that while running the application. The application itself need GPU resources. If your machine doesnt have it will complain.

Comment: Can you explain what you're seeing then? Is you application simply not using the GPU? If you have a GCE VM instance created and have a GPU attached to it and configured (drivers installed), then the GPU resource is accessible.

Comment: @PatrickW, I have compute instance with GPU in it. I can connect to it and run from there. But for that, I need to download the code everytime into compute engine, run maven build and then run the jar file. My code resides on intellij and I cant run from my machine since it doesnt have GPU. I dont want to edit my source code from compute instance in a weird way (executing vim commands). How do I run the code from intellij that connect to my compute instance for GPU execution? Right now I'm wasting compute hours running the maven build on compute engine. Hope you got my question.

Answer (score 0):

The ways to connect to your instances in the Cloud are limited. For Linux, it would be through either the Google Cloud Platform Console or the gcloud command-line tool. You can connect to a Windows instance using graphical connection tools, such as Chrome RDP. You can find more detail on the "Connecting to Instances" documentation [page](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-to-instance). 
In case of Windows, it is possible use these graphical capabilities to edit your code directly on your VM image; this should spare you the effort of using VIM commands. You may even consider installing IntelliJ on your Windows instance. 
In any case, taking into consideration the limited nature of remote connection, you won't be able to edit your code on your local machine using IntelliJ, and running it via remote connection on a GCE instance by means of IntelliJ commands.